# Error when using v.net in GRASS GIS

Tags: grass-gis, network, vector-layer

I'm new to using GRASS GIS and GIS in general. I have a point layer and a line layer which I added on to the layer tree using two .shp files. I need to use v.net tool to create a network by connecting these two layers as edges and nodes respectively so that I can later extract the Steiner tree using v.net.steiner. So I typed in the following code into the console in order to do this:

```
v.net input=cmbRoads@steiner points=bsSnapped@steiner 
out=network_net \ operation=connect threshold=500
```

All I get is the following error message:

[image: error when running v.net on GRASS GIS]

I am using GRASS GIS 7.6.0 on Windows 10.